# Java code for traveling salesman with time windows

Tags: java, traveling-salesman

I am searching some open-source Java code that can be used to solve Traveling Salesman Problem with Time Windows for a single vehicle. Since the problem is very typical, I hope that some open-source libraries are available. Probably, something related to "dynamic programming" or "column generation" methods.

So far, I have used Lagrangean Relaxation algorithm to find shortest route, however in case of time windows this approach is not proper.

Comment: Did you consider using Simulated Annealing?

Comment: @John: no, do you have some link to this algorithm configured for solving TSPTW?

Comment: Yeah @John is right.Try searching for implementation based on Simulated Annealing!
I think this helps you :- http://www.theprojectspot.com/tutorial-post/simulated-annealing-algorithm-for-beginners/6

Comment: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam._

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just take any Vehicle Routing Problem with Time Windows (VRPTW) implementation and add only 1 vehicle to get a TSP with TW.

Here's an open source (Apache License), Java implementation of VRPTW: [Code](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/optaplanner/tree/master/optaplanner-examples/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/examples/vehiclerouting/domain) - [Docs](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#vehicleRouting) - [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BxO3UFmtAPg). But there are plenty more, just google for VRPTW.